# Openvpn's update-resolv-conf set the nameservers in the wrong order with openresolv

Tags: debian, networking, dns, openvpn, resolv.conf

I wanted to switch from `resolvconf` to `openresolv` since openresolv seems more reliable.

I use Mullvad and set my nameserver to `100.64.0.1` as backup nameserver. Now I when use `resolvconf` and start OpenVPN, `update-resolv-conf` writes the nameserver to `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 10.5.0.1
nameserver 100.64.0.1
```

The OpenVPN nameserver is the first one in the list, and I assume the DNS resolver listen to this nameserver before it listens to `100.64.0.1`? When `10.5.0.1` fails it listens to `100.64.0.1`? Or mainly listens to `10.5.0.1`?

When I run OpenVPN with `openresolv`, my `/etc/resolv.conf` looks like this

```
# Generated by resolvconf
nameserver 100.64.0.1
nameserver 10.5.0.1
```

As you can see the order is different with `openresolv`. I want use `openresolv` and `10.5.0.1` as first nameserver in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Anyone know the solution?

**UPDATE**

Before I asked this question I already read that resolv.conf have no priority regarding to the order of the nameservers.

But after some testing I see that I always get `;; SERVER: 100.64.0.1#53(100.64.0.1) (UDP)` as response when I dig with openresolv and when I dig with resolvconf I always get `;; SERVER: 10.5.0.1#53(10.5.0.1) (UDP)`

Comment: There is no order implied by `/etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: Hi Roaima. I read that everywhere but after testing I always get `;; SERVER: 100.64.0.1#53(100.64.0.1) (UDP)` as response when I dig with openresolv and when I dig with resolvconf I always get `;; SERVER: 10.5.0.1#53(10.5.0.1) (UDP)`

Comment: You're lucky. You should not expect an order. There might be one, but you can't guarantee that a different version of the resolver software will work the same way

Comment: I read multiple times what you said on other topics here. But I think you're wrong. After 2,5 months of testing I never saw `;; SERVER: 100.64.0.1#53(100.64.0.1) (UDP)`. I don't think I can but lucky multiple times a day for months long